# vuejs data price total calculation

Tags: vue.js

I want to show the total amount from the data, but how can I do it with vue js in the simplest way?

There is a field where I need to write the sum of the balance amounts, but I cannot do much because the room is outside the for.

```js
 const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            userList: [{
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Prem",
                    gender: "male",
                    balance:'3522'
                },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        name: "Chandu",
                        gender: "female",
                        balance:'2762'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        name: "Jong",
                        gender: "female",
                        balance:'2000'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        name: "Steew",
                        gender: "male",
                        balance:'2000'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 5,
                        name: "Abdollah",
                        gender: "female",
                        balance:'2000'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 6,
                        name: "Jerry",
                        gender: "male",
                        balance:'1500.5'
                    }
                ]
        }
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@2.0.0/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

    <div id="app">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Pice</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(user, i) in userList" class="position-relative">
                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
               <td>{{ user.gender }}</td>
                <td>{{user.balance}}<td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
              <tfoot>
              <tr>
              <td>total number of records: {{userList.length}}</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>Total:</td>
              </tr>
               </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `total` as a computed property using `reduce` function as follows :

```
data: {
   userList: [...],
},
computed:{
  total(){
     return this.userList.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
         return acc+=(+curr)
       },0)
    }
 }

}
```

in template :

```
 <td>Total: {{total}}</td>
```